# How to instantiate class by name in Swift without using the objective-c runtime

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, dynamic, instantiation

Is it possible to create an instance of a Swift class given the name of the class as a string? This should apply for all classes, including user defined, not just default types.

As I understand it, this is impossible to do in pure Swift. Since the language is statically typed, all class types need to be known at compile-time. However, there are several sources demonstrating how this can be done using the Objective-C runtime, which is dynamic.

My solution needs to run on Linux, and right now the objective-c runtime is not available for Swift on Linux. Is it possible to write a c/c++ function that would return an instance of a Swift class if passed a string containing the class name? Or does the design/structure of the language/compiler prohibit this?

Comment: I suspect this might be a case of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What do you need to d this for?

Comment: Our goal is to be able to parse a custom object notation containing type information and use this object notation to dynamically create class instances in Swift.

Comment: If I may ask, why not use existing object serialization techniques?

Comment: We want to be able to take a string and automatically parse it into a class instance for the programmer to consume. We are looking to build a web framework for end-to-end Swift applications, and we are creating a custom object notation for the framework. As part of the object notation, we want custom classes to be automatically instantiated when the object notation files are read in, for the programmer's convenience.

Comment: Is using a custom notation necessary? Core data, NSArchiver, and many of the available ORM systems do exactly what you described.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov CoreData and other ORM systems are only available on Apple platforms and depend on ObjC runtime.

Comment: @b1nary NSArchiver is available on linux, isn't it?

Comment: Probably, you can use [`dlsym`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) on Linux to dynamically check for existence of a symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible in pure Swift. Not because Swift is "statically typed", but because it just hasn't been implemented yet. When using the Objective C runtime (which is dynamic, yes) to do this, you're required to provide the compiler static type information. There is a very limited portion of the program with dynamic behaviour. In a sense, one of the compiler's jobs is to require you to get back into the realm of static type rainbows and safety butterflies by requiring you make compile-time assertions about the runtime behaviour, using explicit casts.

I may be wrong, but I don't think there's a C/C++ workaround for this. Ultimately, you need some sort of runtime system with knowledge of all loaded classes, that can be queried by name. Swift relies on the Objective C runtime for this.

Reflection is a goal for Swift, and the development team has stated that they've increased the reflection meta-data being included as of Swift 3. As they work towards increasing reflective capabilities in Swift. Swift is currently under very rapid evolvement, and the team implementing Swift find reflection to be a lower priority to other goals (conditional conformances, improved generic, ABI stability, API guideline standardization, etc.).

Comment: It is, because it is "statically typed".

Comment: Moreover, the Q was not: "Do cool devs work on Swift?" or "Why do we read 'we are working on it' for years?" or "What would be a good promotion for a programming language, that cannot solve the problem?"

Comment: What is this in response to? `It is, because it is "statically typed".`?

Comment: `"Why do we read 'we are working on it' for years?"` Because that's how the  goals have been prioritized. It's the unfortunately reality of living in a world of finite resources.

Comment: ` "What would be a good promotion for a programming language, that cannot solve the problem?"` what does this even mean?

Comment: Your whole post "explains" your opinion on the goals and road of development of Swift instead of answering the Q. Only the very first sentence gives an answer. The rest is promotion for Swift and nothing else than your opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125476/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-amin-negm-awad).